# Show additional C/C++ header files in Android Studio

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have a large project written in C++ which I'm trying to build now for Android using the Android Studio. The project contains quite a few libraries each having it's own code but the source code files include headers which are shared by all or some of the libraries and reside in directories different from those that contain the source files. This means that in the `CMakeLists.txt` file I have specified them all using `include_directories`. Now I see that when using this CMake script in Android Studio the only files visible in the project browser are the `.cpp` files compiled by targets and the `.h` files that bare the same name as their corresponding source. I wish to be able to quickly edit all of the project files, not only those that have been detected by the Android Studio and therefore it would be useful to have all the common headers listed in the project browser. How do I specify additional files/directories to be shown?

I have already tried doing that by saying in the `.gradle` script

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs "../whatever/"
        }
    }
}
```

But that is clearly not ideal because those directories are shown in `java` folder in the browser and any error detected in those header files cannot navigate to the problematic line.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: No, the issue has been known for a [long time](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37115536) and they lately resigned it, so we can only have hope.

Comment: Ok, then what do you use for debugging c++ in android ? I use eclipse but sometimes it gets hard :(

Comment: I do use Android Studio, the debugger "works" sometimes and sometimes is a pain in the ... but it generally works. The only issue I have is finding the files if i want to say place a breakpoint somewhere since there is no mention of them in the browser, I use Xcode then because the same code base in my case is compiled for iOS and Mac. Hope they solve it soon.